# Problem when concatenating lists to string with newline

Tags: python, string, list

I would like to concatenate 2 lists with new line.

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4,5]
```

The expected output format is:

```
1,2
3,4,5
```

My code is:

```
final = []
final.append(list1)
final.append(list2)

final = '\n'.join([str(i) for i in finallist])
```

But it returns:

```
'[1, 2]\n[4, 5, 6]'
```

Because I am going to save this output to txt file, so it has to be a string and print() does not work here. Could anyone advise how can I solve this problem? Thank you very much!

Comment: When you call `str()` on an entire list, you get `[ ]` in the result.  It sounds like you want to call `str()` on the _contents_ of the list, not _the list itself_.

Comment: @JohnGordon apparently no. calling `str()` on a list makes the whole thing a string

Comment: @Matiiss I'm not sure what you're saying "no" to?  Calling `str()` on a list certainly does include `[ ]` in the output string...

Comment: @JohnGordon in that case I misinterpreted your statement of getting `[]` as I thought it meant an empty list but even if you get `[]` in the string too you can `.replace()` them

Answer (score 1):

does this fix your issue (its your expected output):

```
list1 = [1,2]
list2 = [3,4,5]

final = [list1, list2]

final = '\n'.join([str(i).replace('[', '').replace(']', '') for i in final])
with open('yourfile.txt', 'w') as file:
    file.write(final)
```

Comment: Because I am going to save this output to txt file, so it has to be a string and print() does not work here.

Comment: @user14504696 I edited my post is this what you wanted?

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you! I found the result showed in Jupyter notebook still has \n while it is okay when saving to txt file.

Answer (score 0):

Consider the operations here:

```
final = []  # An empty list
final.append(list1)  # List contains a list: [[1, 2]]
final.append(list2)  # List contains 2 lists: [[1, 2], [3, 4, 5]]

[str(i) for i in finallist]  # Convert each list into a string, put it in a new list
# e.g. This list will contain two values: ['[1, 2]', '[4, 5, 6]']
```

It sounds like you want to have commas between values in the list, and newlines between lists. Converting the entire list into a string will include the brackets, when you just want to convert each entry into its own string. Like so:

```
list1 = [str(i) for i in list1]
list2 = [str(i) for i in list2]
final = [list1, list2]
print('\n'.join([','.join(i) for i in final]))
```

Comment: Because I am going to save this output to txt file, so it has to be a string and print() does not work here.

Comment: @user14504696 That's okay; just write `'\n'.join([','.join(i) for i in final])` to the output file.

Comment: Yes, this works. Thank you! I found the result showed in Jupyter notebook still has \n while it is okay when saving to txt file.